# Конвертирование System.Data.DbType к System.Type

Tags: c#, sqlite

У меня в базе данных SQlite в одном из столбцов данные вещественного типа(float). Так вот я не нашел в [списке](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx) типа, который бы подходил для float. Пробовал DbType.Single, но выдает исключение:
**Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "double" в "float". Существует явное преобразование (требуется приведение типа?)** 
Можно ли как-то привести к типу float?

Comment: Convert.ToSingle(object arg) ?

Comment: Может, попробуйте double? Чтобы конвертировало из double в double?